# Searching Tmbd Movie DB - React.js - Searches won't render until app recompiles

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is my component. The issue I'm having is that when I enter a search nothing happens until I save in the code editor and the app recompiles. Then the searches render on the page. What is the correct way to make the api call so the searches render on the page without refreshing or recompiling?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";


function Movie() {
    const [movieList, setMovieList] = useState([]);
    const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState("");

    const API_KEY = "10940971fec2e5fb49d3d2e4797d9da5";
    const discoverEndpoint = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}`;
    const searchEndpoint = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&query=${searchQuery}`
    const endpoints = searchQuery ? searchEndpoint : discoverEndpoint;

    const getMovie = () => {  
        const options = {
       method: 'GET',
       headers: {
         accept: 'application/json',
         Authorization: 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiIxMDk0MDk3MWZlYzJlNWZiNDlkM2QyZTQ3OTdkOWRhNSIsInN1YiI6IjY1NjU2MDE0MTU2Y2M3MDEwY2IzMTUxMSIsInNjb3BlcyI6WyJhcGlfcmVhZCJdLCJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoxfQ.S8rXI1em-12sf3qRFhWknWLPRSVxOJnGnyFjK6XsdLI'
       }
     };
         fetch(endpoints, options)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => setMovieList(response.results))
        .catch(err => console.error(err))
     
    }

        useEffect(() => {
           getMovie();
       }, [])
   
       console.log(movieList);
        return (
            <div>
                 <div className="searchBar">
                  <input type="text" value={searchQuery}
                   onChange = {(e) => {
                    setSearchQuery(e.target.value)
                    console.log(e.target.value)
                   }}
                  />
                  <button>Show All</button>
                </div>
                {
                    movieList.map((movie) => (
                        <>
                        <img src = {`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${movie.poster_path}`}/>
                        <p>{movie.original_title}</p>
                        <p>{movie.overview}</p>
                        <p>{movie.release_date}</p>
                        </>
                    ))
                }
            </div>
        )
    

}

export default Movie
```

I tried using axios to call the API and attempted to make it an asyncronous function, but got erros from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your getMovie() method only runs on first render. However, you need it to run whenever searchQuery changes.

In useEffect's, dependency array, add 'searchQuery' and move the below lines inside getMovie() method-

```
const discoverEndpoint = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movieapi_key=${API_KEY}`;
const searchEndpoint = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movieapi_key=${API_KEY}&query=${searchQuery}`
const endpoints = searchQuery ? searchEndpoint : discoverEndpoint;
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you!

Comment: Great! Can you accept the answer if it works for you?